# Is a matrix a control system with memory?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering

In control systems, a system is said to have memory if the output is dependent on previous inputs. By that definition, is a matrix of arbitrary dimensions a system with memory? (I am new to controls.)

Comment: Wait until you do state space math and evaluate control systems using matrices...

Comment: A matrix is a bunch of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If we have to evaluate it on a matrix, we cannot consider it as a memory system. There should be a historical data record in line with the processes applied in the definition of memory systems. However, matrices are formed by random assignments. As long as the matrix creation is continued, the newly created matrix output will not use the historical data, so the past assignments will not have a counterpart in the system.